# ipython map_async input and output data

Tags: python, dictionary, parallel-processing, ipython

I am new to the IPython parallel package but really want to get it going.  What I have is a 4D numpy array which I want to run through slices,rows,columns and process the 4th dimension (time). The processing is a minimization routine that takes a bit of time which is why I would like to parallelize it.

```
from IPython.parallel import Client
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pylab import *

c = Client()

v = c.load_balanced_view()
v.block=False

def process( src, freq, d ):
        # Get slice, row, col
        sl,r,c = src

        # Get data
        mm = d[:,sl,c,r]

        # Call fitting routine
        <fiting routine that requires freq, mm and outputs multiple parameters> 

        return <output parameters??>


##  Create the mask of what we are going to process
mask = zeros(d[0].shape)
mask[sl][ nonzero( d[0,sl] > 10*median(d[0]) ) ] = 1

# find all non-zero points in the mask
points = array(nonzero( mask == 1)).transpose()

# Call async
asyncresult = v.map_async( process, points, freq=freq, d=d )
```

My function "process" requires two parameters: 1) freq is a numpy array (100,1) and 2) d which is (100, 50, 110, 110) or so.  I want to retrieve several parameters from the fitting.

All the examples I have seen that use map_async have simple lambda functions etc and the outputs seem to be trivial.

What I want is to apply "process" to every point in d where the mask is not zero and to have maps of the output parameters in the same space.  [Added:  I am getting "process() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given) ].

(Step 2 of this might be required as I am passing a huge numpy array "d" to each process. But once I figure out the data passing I should hopefully be able to figure out a more efficient way of doing this.)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I got around the data passing problem by doing

```
def mapper(x):
    return apply(x[0], x[1:])
```

And calling map_async with a list of tuples where the first element is my function and the rest of the elements are the parameters to my function.

```
asyncResult = pool.map_async(mapper, [(func, arg1, arg2) for arg1, arg2 in myArgs])
```

I tried a lambda first but apparently that couldn't be pickled so that was a no go.

Comment: Hi, Daniel. When I use your solution with the function def f(x): return x I got the error 'DummyMod object no attribute 'f''. If instead I use cos(x), it works fine. Can you tell what is wrong with my function f? Thanks.